# Moski Gist-Blogger Not Loading Gists in Chrome (for Gists in Blogger Dynamic Views)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, github, blogger, gist

I have been using [Moski's Gist-Blogger](https://github.com/moski/gist-Blogger) for inserting GitHub Gists into Blogger Dynamic Views.

My use of it is as follows:

```
<div class="gistLoad" data-id="4713292" id="gist-4713292">
Loading code....</div>

<script src="https://raw.github.com/moski/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, currently, the gists do not load in Chrome. Chrome's console prints the following error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://raw.github.com/moski/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistLoader.js?_=1401752376660'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.

How can I fix this? Is there a working fork of the Moski script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a Pull Request to fix this: https://github.com/moski/gist-Blogger/pull/6

Until it's merged you can replace the script at the end of your posts to:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/git-m1chael-dg/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It worked for me: http://ru.khroliz.com/2014/06/python-webdriver-webelement.html

Comment: Thanks for this. It has been merged as of July 22 and now you can use `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/moski/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: not working for me, 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/git-m1chael-dg/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistLoader.js' getting 404 error code